# CSS transform rotate not "centered"

Tags: css, css-transforms

[link] https://likeit.net/2

The accordion dropdown "triangle icons" are pivoting around an unexpected axis.

I could use some advice please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the width and the height of the triangle.

Then to transform, use `transform: rotate(-90deg);`

Comment: you probably also need to adjust the `transform-origin` property in some level

Comment: so edit your answer and add that, why are you commenting it

Answer (score 0):

Add (or change to) `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` to rotate the element around its center in case this parameter has been set differently.

Comment: 50% 50% is the default, so adding that will make no difference (unless set already)